# SOLR exact and partial match

Tags: solr, lucene

I need to implement some specific number format full and partial search with SOLR.

The format is like that:
"01-1-00050-1" or 
"M-1-02-00035-14"

If I enter:
01; 01-1; 01-1-00050; 50; and similar I should get the match by "01-1-00050-1".
But If I, for example, try to find 1-01 it should not match.

My current thoughts:

1) Break the number to tokens by "-"

```
<fieldType name="specific_number" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" />
        />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
              generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" />
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn`t work, because there is no position checking for tokens. If the input is "1-01" it will still find "01-1".

Also I need to be able to find without specifying zeros in the middle. I was thinking about

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="0{3,4}" replacement="" />
```

But the "050" would fail in this case...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: From your examples it doesn't seem like tokenization is needed. Will the query string always match part of the token? (and not searching by "01 00050") ?

Comment: Use a [phrase query](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Terms): `"01-1"`, instead of `01-1`

Answer (score 0):

Most of your example seem to require no tokenization and just an NGram filter, so the input matches any valid prefix of your indexed text.

This does not address why **50** should match however, it seems to be right in the middle of the string. Also, it's not clear what should happen with **M-1** in the second example, is it supposed to match by **M-1** or just **1** or something else.

So, you may need to clarify the extra rule(s) that are not just prefix matches.